# How to create an immutable and consistent hash of a string that will be the same every time a python program is run?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash

I have a column (let's call it STR) with string values that do not change. e.g. but receive new values over time:

| STR |
| --- |
| abc123 |
| efg456 |
| hij789 |

And I'd like to create a column that has a numeric value attached to each string value in the column above. This numeric value should not change each time the program is run and should be consistent in length (e.g. each should be 7 digits long). An example output:

| STR | ID |
| --- | --- |
| abc123 | 0125699 |
| efg456 | 6589455 |
| hij789 | 0995525 |

Say additional values are added to the STR column and I had to rerun the code, I would want the existing generated ID values to remain the same, but additional STR values to receive a new generated ID. E.g.:

| STR | ID |
| --- | --- |
| abc123 | 0125699 |
| efg456 | 6589455 |
| hij789 | 0995525 |
| klm101 | 0555989 |
| nop558 | 5595959 |

I've tried using a hash function, but this seems to change every time the program is run:

```
def generate_id(s):
     return abs(hash(s)) % (15 ** 15)

df['ID'] = df['STR'].apply(generate_id)
```

Any suggestions on how I could achieve the desired output? Can't seem to find a solution that is consistent after numerous executions of the program. The end goal of this is to create an ID value that can identify the STR column without revealing it's value across many different dataframes.

Comment: You likely want to check out `hashlib.sha256()` rather than `hash()`

Comment: something like `int.from_bytes(hashlib.sha256("Hello World".encode("utf-8")).digest(), "big") `

Comment: For more context, `hash` uses a randomly-generated hash *seed* every time Python runtime boots. You could set `PYTHONHASHSEED` to 0 and sidestep this but generally the behavior is not guaranteed, unlike a standard hash function like SHA 256.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's hard to understand the question. Most importantly, *What do you mean by "a column"*? For example, are you using Pandas? If so, how are you creating the DataFrame? If you are **saving data** (i.e., have a **file** that somehow records the strings, that you will load when the program starts up and create a Pandas DataFrame), then a) *why not explain any of this up front?* and b) why not *just also save the ID values in the same file*?

Comment: *"without revealing'* - Does that mean you want it to be hard/impossible to figure out the string from the number?

Answer (score 0):

For a numerical value, you could create a function to hash it, get the hex, and use `int(s, base=16)` to get the numeric value. So, the code would become

```py
import hashlib

def numericvalue_from_string(s):
    h = hashlib.new('sha1') #for shortest results with sha, if you are ok with big numbers then sha256 or sha512 also work.
    h.update(s.encode())
    hx = h.hexdigest()
    return int(hx, base=16)
```

so if I run `numericvalue_from_string('m')` it will yield `611156256285597126173522716470136971498835711720` (sha1)

To truncate this to a lenth of, e.g. 7 characters, you can `str(numericvalue_from_string(...))[0:7]`.

Hope this helps.